# How to map POJO in to DTO, if fields are with different name

Tags: java, mapping, dto, pojo, apache-commons-beanutils

***Problem description:***

I have a POJO object, which is mapped from database. Which having attributes(column) with same name as in database table. But it required some changes and I will have to use DTOs. But problem is that DTO having attributes with different names as defined in database table,(*because of this I am mapping database table to POJO and then POJO to DTO*) so at the time of mapping I have to use field and field mapping(One field of POJO and one field of DTO object), and that will take 50 lines of code( *database table having 50 columns*). Is there any solution to map directly to my POJO with DTO?   Or is there a way to map database table to POJO/DTO if database table and POJO/DTO having diffrent column names?

***For example***

```
public class EmployeePOJO {

    String EMP_ID;
    String EMP_NAME;
    String EMP_SALERY;
    String EMP_DOB;
    String EMP_CONTACT_NO;
    String EMP_ADDRESS;
    String EMP_BLOOD_GROUP;
    String ASSIGNED_PROJECT;
    String PROJECT_MANAGER;
    String ROLE;

    //Getters and setters
}



public class EmployeeDTO {

    //String EMP_ID;
    //String EMP_NAME;
    String salery;            //EMP_SALERY;
    //String EMP_DOB;
    String phoneNumber;       //EMP_CONTACT_NO;
    String address;           //EMP_ADDRESS;
    //String EMP_BLOOD_GROUP;
    String currentProject;    //ASSIGNED_PROJECT;
    String projectManager;    //PROJECT_MANAGER;
    String role;              //ROLE;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Why do you have capitalized names for the fields in your pojo? This should be camelcased.

Comment: Its not a real POJO. I putted it just for example and showing that POJO's fields as same as database table column names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dozer/develop ? (not sure it maps your needs,but take a  look)
http://dozer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Cris This down vote not from my side Cris. And if answer will helpful in my case sure I will upvote. And thanks for downvote on my question.

Comment: Maybe you don;t want to use it but Dozer might be used for what you described.So i am really curios how can i see who voted - and to explain why

Comment: It is like someone ask about ORM and people who respond with alternatives to Hibernate m like EclipseLink are downvoted...because they don't want to use it

Comment: Although I really don't like dozer, it is a possible solution...
Why do you say 'this is not as what I want'?

Comment: @Cris Hey I am trying to use Dozer. It seems I will solve my problem using it. Actually in previous I was with BeanUtils and I was trying to solve my problem with same. But after reading documentation of Dozer, I am with Dozer also.

Comment: @Cris Can you sare some links about to source code and tutorials of Dozer, please.

Comment: you have pretty much here all http://dozer.sourceforge.net/ .There is also an eclipse plugin

Answer (score 4):

My [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper) is another library worth checking out. It offers a fluent API to map properties as opposed to using string references or XML.

Check out the ModelMapper site for more info:

http://modelmapper.org

Answer (score 1):

You can add `@JsonProperty("salery")` for mapping the **EMP_SALERY** field on the top of the field.
which uses the import of `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;`

This works for me when using the ModelMapper.

If again deserialization is your concern you have 2 options.

```
@JsonProperty("EMP_SALERY")
    public byte getEMP_SALERY() {
    return red;
}

@JsonProperty("salery")
     public void setEMP_SALERY(byte red) {
     this.red = red;
}
```

The other way is using Alias

```
@JsonAlias({"salery", "EMP_SALERY"})
private String EMP_SALERY;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [JMapper Framework](http://code.google.com/p/jmapper-framework/). 
With a little configuration (with annotations or xml) you're ready to map